# Question about changing marker of scatter during animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with changing direction of "triangle marker" in scatter during animation of points move. 
So I have 100 points which are moving randomly on the area and in every iteration they can change direction of move (every point separately from another/ they are independent). I read from pickle location of every point in every iteration with them direction and I wish to plot it. What every 10 moves points are changed by another generations of points which are still moving randomly. My code kinda works but not like it should. The direction of every point is set at the beggining of the every generation but is not changing after every iteration. Could someone help me to change it? ;)

```
def update(i, data, agent, texts, NUMBER_OF_POINTS): 

    x_N, y_N = [], []
    x_S, y_S = [], []
    x_W, y_W = [], []
    x_E, y_E = [], []
    for point, coordinate in IT.islice(data, NUMBER_OF_POINTS):
        if point in range(100):
            if coordinate[1] == Direction.N:
                texti = texts[point]
                x, y = coordinate[0].cpu().numpy()
                x_N.append(x)
                y_N.append(y)
                texti.set_position((x, y))
                agent_N.set_offsets(np.column_stack([x_N, y_N]))
                agent_N.set_paths([MarkerStyle("^").get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle("^").get_transform())])
            elif coordinate[1] == Direction.S:
                texti = texts[point]
                x, y = coordinate[0].cpu().numpy()
                x_S.append(x)
                y_S.append(y)
                texti.set_position((x, y))
                agent_S.set_offsets(np.column_stack([x_S, y_S]))
                agent_S.set_paths([MarkerStyle("v").get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle("v").get_transform())])
            elif coordinate[1] == Direction.W:
                texti = texts[point]
                x, y = coordinate[0].cpu().numpy()
                x_W.append(x)
                y_W.append(y)
                texti.set_position((x, y))
                agent_W.set_offsets(np.column_stack([x_W, y_W]))
                agent_W.set_paths([MarkerStyle("<").get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle("<").get_transform())])
             else:
                texti = texts[point]
                x, y = coordinate[0].cpu().numpy()
                x_E.append(x)
                y_E.append(y)
                texti.set_position((x, y))
                agent_E.set_offsets(np.column_stack([x_E, y_E]))
     return [agent_N, agent_S, agent_W, agent_E] + texts

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matplotlib.animation.Animation._blit_draw = _blit_draw
    num_frames = NUMBER_OF_GENERATIONS*SINGLE_LIFETIME
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    agent_N = ax.scatter([0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, [0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, c="lightblue", s=100)
    agent_S = ax.scatter([0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, [0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, c="lightblue", s=100)
    agent_E = ax.scatter([0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, [0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, c="lightblue", s=100)
    agent_W = ax.scatter([0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, [0] * NUMBER_OF_POINTS, c="lightblue", s=100)
    texts = []
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_AGENTS):
        t = ax.text(0, 0, str(i), fontsize=10, animated=True)
        texts.append(t)
    path = "output.txt"
    data = get_data(path)
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, range(1, num_frames + 1), init_func=init, blit=True, fargs=(data, agent_N, agent_S, agent_W, agent_E, mushroom, toadstool, texts, title, NUMBER_OF_POINTS), interval=1000, repeat=False,)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem. It would help if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with emphasis on *minimal* (i.e. only what's necessary to reproduce the problem) and *complete* (as in one can copy and paste your code and see the problem by oneself)

Comment: My problem is simple I think, but I don't know how to solve it. I have "points" which are moving in every step of iteration in some direction ("^","v","<",">"). I want to illustrate direction of every point. Right now the code which I attached takes direction only in first iteration and point for example is moving in some iteration on north but the marker is "<" what means "west".

Answer (score 1):

The point of my comment is that it's going to be near impossible to tell you what's wrong with your code when we cannot *run* your code.

In any case, here is a simple animation where the markers change depending on the direction of travel, maybe that'll help you figure something out. If not, then consider providing an actual MVCE

```
np.random.seed(12345)
N_points = 20
N_frames_per_direction = 20

O_path = MarkerStyle('o').get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle('o').get_transform())
N_path = MarkerStyle('^').get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle('^').get_transform())
S_path = MarkerStyle('v').get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle('v').get_transform())
E_path = MarkerStyle('>').get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle('>').get_transform())
W_path = MarkerStyle('<').get_path().transformed(MarkerStyle('<').get_transform())

x_init,y_init = 20*np.random.random(size=(2,N_points)) # initial position
dxes = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=(N_points,N_frames_per_direction)), 
                       np.zeros(shape=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction)),
                       np.random.normal(loc=-1, scale=1, size=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction)),
                       np.zeros(shape=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction))], axis=1)
dyes = np.concatenate([np.zeros(shape=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction)),
                       np.random.normal(loc=-1, scale=1, size=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction)),
                       np.zeros(shape=(N_points, N_frames_per_direction)),
                       np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=(N_points,N_frames_per_direction)),], axis=1)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter([],[], marker='o')
ax.set_xlim(-10,50)
ax.set_ylim(-25,25)

def init():
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x_init,y_init])
    return sc,

def animate(i):
    x,y = sc.get_offsets().T
    x += dxes[:,i]
    y += dyes[:,i]
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])
    sc.set_paths([E_path if dx>0 
                  else W_path if dx<0 
                  else N_path if dy>0 
                  else S_path if dy<0 
                  else O_path for dx,dy in zip(dxes[:,i], dyes[:,i])])
    return sc,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=4*N_frames_per_direction, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]